# Android Ubiquiti Bridge network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, android

I have the following setup:

debian machine with configuration:

```
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.2.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
```

debian machine is connected to Ubiquiti Rocket 5M in AP mode with transparent bridge at ip 192.168.2.2 gw 192.168.2.1

Rocket is connected to a station Ubiquiti 5M Bullet at ip 192.168.2.2 with GW 192.168.2.1

Rocket is connected over micro-usb to ethernet adapter to rooted android Samsung s4 running Cyanogenmod at 192.168.2.5.

The following strange thing occurs:

on 192.168.2.1:
       `ping -b 192.168.2.255` results in a response from 192.168.2.2 and 192.168.2.3

on 192.168.2.5
        `ping -b 192.168.2.255` results in a response from 192.168.2 and .3, but not .1. However `ping 192.168.2.2` or `ping 192.168.2.3` results in no response. Only the broadcast ping works.

> 1) Why can 192.168.2.5 see .2 and .3 only during broadcast ping?
>
> 2) Why can 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.2.5 both see 192.168.2.2 and 192.168.2.3 but 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.2.5 can't see each other?

ps:
I have tested replacing 192.168.2.5 with a windows laptop and all the devices can see each other. Also on the android to setup eth0 I did:

`ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.5; route add default gw 192.168.2.1 dev eth0; netcfg eth0 up`

Answer (score 0):

[Tentative answer, open to correction]

Normally within one IP subnet you send to an IP and do not need a gateway as its local. The only "decision" being made is ARP, which port is this IP known to be on/in the direction of.

When your remote android client pings an IP it sends out a unicast packet on its only active interface towards the bridge, but the bridge is "dumb" and just forwards unicast traffic across the wireless link which gets to the router missing its target mac. The router wont send it back as that could create a layer 2 storm.

Then you try a bcast ping which inherently is not unicast and it seems the bridge will not blindly forward it (probably a good idea in terms of congestion) but instead receive and respond to it. The fact that you don't see a response from .1 supports this.

It may be a good idea to add a router on the far side of the wireless link to divide broadcast domains, usually you do not want excessive traffic bursts over what is often the busiest/slowest part of the network.